# remove dotted line around the radio buttons in firefox

Tags: html, css

There are some posts which suggested the below fixes for removing the dotted line around the radio buttons as below:

```
 1)   input[type=radio]
  {
 &:focus
  {
-moz-appearance: none !important;
-moz-border-bottom-colors: transparent !important;
-moz-border-left-colors: transparent !important;
-moz-border-right-colors: transparent !important;
-moz-border-top-colors: transparent !important;
  }
  }

  2) input[type=radio]:-moz-focursing
   {
    outline : none;
     }
```

However the above two fixes did not work for me.Is there any other css to be written to remove the unwanted border around the radio buttons in firefox.

Thanks in adavance,
Balaji.

Comment: `-moz-appearance: none;` works only when the border is resulting from a GTK+ theme, most common on Linux systems. It will typically do nothing on most commonly-used OS's with the standard configurations to use GTK+. More broadly, radio buttons in Firefox seems to rely on some OS-dependent features which may be explaining why this is so difficult to debug or solve. In the absence of testing, I recommend keeping `-moz-appearance: none;` in the code so it doesn't break on Linux systems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 input[type="radio"] {
        outline: none;
    }
```

**OR**

```
input[type="radio"]::-moz-focus-inner {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks Srinivas, I just tried ur answer , it did not work

Comment: can you reproduce your issue in fiddle.

Comment: sorry, in firefox , the focus is not going to the radio buttons in fiddle

Comment: This did not work for me on Firefox 94.0. The elements are ending up with a 2px border no matter what, which is breaking my layout.